# Connecting to Spark through SSH

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a one node hadoop cluster set up. I am trying to execute SPARK Scripts from my edge node to hit the hadoop node through SSH. I am looking for how to execute SPARK scripts from edge node to hit the hadoop node(where my spark exists). Any command? Any settings?

Comment: Are you trying to use **yarn** or **standalone** mode?

Comment: standalone- cloudera VM

Comment: I am trying to run command by command from my edge node to hit my hadoop node

Comment: spark and hadoop both are in different machine?

Comment: nope. Spark is sitting on top of HDFS. So both are in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).